# Error after adding in-app messaging sdk to gradle

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, build.gradle, firebase-in-app-messaging

[image: Screenshot of my error]

Error shows after adding in-app message sdk.

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:17.0.5'

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5'
implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:12.0.1'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:17.0.5'

implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1'
implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:12.0.1'
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.1.0'
def room_version = "1.1.1"
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$room_version"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"

debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.6.3'
releaseImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.6.3'
// Optional, if you use support library fragments:
debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-support-fragment:1.6.3'
 }
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
 apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
```

minsdk is 16 and targetsdk is 26.

Unable to resolve, tried updating my appcompat and Firebase libraries but no result.

Answer (score 0):

implementation in your `build.gradle` file this support library `android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.1.0`.

Comment: this line exist in my code and also updated my existing code pls check it.